# mysql query to fetch details of users between specific dates

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query="SELECT DISTINCT ind_id,indentdate,submitted_by 
        FROM raiseindent 
        where submitted_by='$nm' 
          AND indentdate BETWEEN '$fromDate' AND '$toDate' 
          OR indentdate BETWEEN '$fromDate' AND '$toDate' 
          OR submitted_by='$nm'";
```

here `$nm` is username

I am not getting any errors, this query fetching records if I use only `$nm` (User Name) or between two dates

If I use to serach specific user name and two dates it is fetching all users records between selected dates

I need specific only the results from entered user name in username field to serach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$query="SELECT DISTINCT ind_id,indentdate,submitted_by 
        FROM raiseindent 
        where submitted_by='$nm' 
          AND indentdate BETWEEN '$fromDate' AND '$toDate'";
```

I dont think it need to be any more complicated than this.

Or if it is possible for `$nm` to be empty or the dates to be empty then do those tests in PHP and dynamically build the query accordingly rather than trying to get the SQL to do it all for you

```
$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT ind_id,indentdate,submitted_by 
    FROM raiseindent 
    WHERE ';


if ( !empty($nm) && $nm != 'ALL' ) {
    $sql .= "submitted_by='$nm' AND ";
}
if ( !empty($fromDate) && !empty($toDate) ) {
    $sql .= " indentdate BETWEEN '$fromDate' AND '$toDate' ";
}
$sql = rtrim($sql, 'AND ');
```

Comment: I am getting results when i used this, but if i want to get the all users details, I mean in username column insetad of name I can add ALL to get all users data between selected dates what to do?

Comment: Else let me know how to run more than one query at time if if first query results empty

Comment: Does that do what you mean by passing an ALL in the $nm field?

Comment: yes if admin want see the details of all users data I want to put ALL to fetch all records form all users.

Comment: I tried the query you have sent but getting error error in query

Comment: Echo the $sql after this code is run. and what is the error. Remember I have no database to test this on

Comment: $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT ind_id,indentdate,submitted_by 
    FROM raiseindent 
    WHERE ';


if ( !empty($nm) && $nm != 'ALL' ) {
    $sql .= "submitted_by='$nm' AND ";
}
if ( !empty($fromDate) && !empty($toDate) ) {
    $sql .= " indentdate BETWEEN '$fromDate' AND '$toDate' ";
}
$sql = rtrim($nm, 'ALL');
$result=mysqli_query($dbc,$sql) or die('error in query');

echo $sql;

Comment: Sorry a typo, please change the `rtrim()` as I have in the anwwer

Comment: $sql = rtrim(); i changed last like this getting error Warning: rtrim() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\wamp\www\stmanager\viewindentadmin.php on line 62 and Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in C:\wamp\www\stmanager\viewindentadmin.php on line 64 and error in query

Comment: I am getting accurate results hat-sup sir

Comment: $sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT ind_id,indentdate,submitted_by 
    FROM raiseindent 
    WHERE ';


if ( !empty($nm) && $nm != 'ALL' ) {
    $sql .= "submitted_by='$nm' AND ";
}
if ( !empty($fromDate) && !empty($toDate) ) {
    $sql .= " indentdate BETWEEN '$fromDate' AND '$toDate' ";
}
$sql = rtrim($sql);                                                       this is a final code

Comment: after this i am printing the results if no results how to show error message?

Answer (score 0):

Though it's already answered; for a note try using `>=` and `<=`  to have the exact start and end date inclusive, instead `BETWEEN` operator like

```
SELECT DISTINCT ind_id,indentdate,submitted_by 
        FROM raiseindent 
        where submitted_by='$nm' 
          AND (indentdate >= '$fromDate' AND indentdate <= '$toDate');
```

Comment: Any reason why you would prefer this form to the BETWEEN? Or is it just preference? I am just interested

Comment: this is working how to fetch all users data by entering ALL instead of $nm?

Comment: @JalavahiniTechnologies, then just omit the filter condition `submitted_by='$nm'` which will fetch records for all users.